# How can I change normal ViewController to PageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

my project starts in a normal ViewController now I want to use Push segues but that only works with a `PageViewController`. Now how can I change my ViewController with .h and .m with code in it to a `PageViewController`

Comment: Do you just want to use push segues? Or do you actually need a PageViewController?

Comment: So I want to get a PageView like iOS's HomeScreen

Comment: And I don't want a NavigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect.

PageViewControllers don't handle push segues, navigation controllers do.

A page view controller manages a series of pages. It is kind of like a table view or collection view, except that the contents are full pages, and use either a page curl or side-scroll animation between pages.

A navigation controller manages a stack of view controllers and you use push and pop commands to add view controllers to the stack or take them off the stack.

If you want to put your app's current view controller inside a navigation controller, there is a menu command for that in Interface Builder. Select the view controller, pull down the edit menu, and look for "Embed in>Navigation Controller." If you select that menu item, Interface Builder will wrap the selected view controller inside a navigation controller. I think that's what you want.

Comment: Yes does this work for pages like on iOS's HomeScreen?

Comment: I want that it's like on HomeScreen so background stays online icons change

Comment: Ok, so your use of the term push segue was completely wrong. You want a  group of icons that you can slide back and forth.

Comment: You probably want to use either a UIScrollView set up for page scrolling, or a UICollectionView. For using a scroll view, open the UIScrollView Class reference in the Xcode help system, and search for the string "PageControl". That should lead you to a sample application by that name, that implements a scroll view that scrolls by pages. It would be pretty easy to adapt that sample app to scroll a set of icons on top of a transparent background, with a static image underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting a little confused about what PageViewController is. If you want to Push segues your view controller must be inside of a UINavigation Controller. You will init your first view controller as the root view controller and then you will be able to "push" on top of the navigation stack. No PageViewController needed.